# css clip-path not working in Opera and Internet Explorer

Tags: css, svg, cross-browser, clip

I need to to use clipping to implement a progressbar-like element with a diagonal right edge, and css3 clip-path seems to be the best option.

I could easily enough find a solution working in Firefox and Chrome, but after hours of trials I could not make any progress in either Internet Explorer or Opera: they seem to simply ignore the clip-path!

I studied Opera better, and it does support clip-path (while -o-clip-path does not seem to exist) since few versions.

here is my complete html file, including css and all, ready to be copy/paste-ed and run, anyone has any tips? Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Prova Clipping</title>

  <svg>
    <defs>
      <clipPath id="prova_clip">
        <polygon points="10 0, 1000 0, 1000 50, 0 50"/>
      </clipPath>
    </defs>
  </svg>

  <style type="text/css">
  body {
    color: purple;
    background-color: blue; 
  }
  #barra {
    position: relative;
    margin: 50px;
    width:300px;

    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);     
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);      
    -o-transform: rotate(180deg);       
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);      
  }
  .barra {
    position: absolute;
    height: 50px;
  }
  #barra_sfondo {
    width: 20%;
    background: linear-gradient(grey, black);

    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);     
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);      
    -o-transform: rotate(180deg);       
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);      

    -webkit-clip-path: url(#prova_clip);
    -ms-clip-path: url(#prova_clip);
    clip-path: url(#prova_clip);
  }
  #barra_colore {
    width: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, yellow, red); 
  }
  </style>  
</head>

<body>
    <div id="barra">
        <svg class="barra" id="barra_colore">
            <polygon points="0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%"/>
        </svg>
        <svg class="barra" id="barra_sfondo">
            <polygon points="0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%"/>
        </svg>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

For most cross-browser support, this is code you need:

```
-webkit-mask: url(#prova_clip); // Opera and Chrome
mask: url(#prova_clip);
clip-path: url(#prova_clip); // Firefox
```

`mask-image` propety is currenty supported only in webkit browsers under prefix while Firefox recognizes unprefixed `clip-path` property. I don't know why but it seems -webkit-clip-path doesn't work in Opera.

Internet Explorer currently doesn't support neither mask or clip-path property.

Reference links:
http://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path
http://caniuse.com/#search=mask

Answer (score -3):

Please Use Below reference for CSS.

/ Selector Hacks *****/

```
/* IE6 and below */
* html #div { 
height: 300px;
}

/* IE7 */
*+html #div { 
height: 300px;
}

/* IE8 */
#div {
height: 300px\0/;
}

/*IE7 & IE8*/   
#div {
height: 300px\9;
}

/*Hide from IE6 and LOWER*/
#div {
height/**/: 300px;
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question.